# Conditional cast from 'AppDelegate' to 'UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate' always succeeds (Flutter)

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I've tried to connect iPhone to build my flutter project, but this error occurs :

`Conditional cast from 'AppDelegate' to 'UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate' always succeeds`

I guess it might be related with local notifications, but have no idea why the error occurs and how to fix it.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: `AppDelegate` inherits from `FlutterAppDelegate` which is compliant with `FlutterAppLifeCycleProvider` which is `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` compliant. So you shouldn't need the cast: `self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` should be `self`

Comment: @Larme Awesome, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What @Larme mentioned in the comments is correct. There's no need for self (FlutterAppDelegate) to be casted since AppDelegate inherits the FlutterAppDelegate class. The code should be

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

If you're using flutter_local_notifications plugin, you can also try removing `?` as demonstrated in the [sample](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift) provided in their docs.